# Контент (Position:relative) накладывается на хэдэр (positioin:sticky) при скролле

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, слайдер

В код вставил сниппет слайдера (position:relative), при этом при скролле весь контент слайдера накладывается поверх на header (position:sticky). Происходит примерно вот это. Подскажите, как решить проблему?

```
  #block-for-slider {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#viewport {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#slidewrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% * 4);
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.67,.01,.23,1);
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.67,.01,.23,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.67,.01,.23,1);
}

#slidewrapper, #slidewrapper ul, #slidewrapper li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.slide {
    min-height: 540px;
    width: calc(100%/4);
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.slide-img {
    width: 100%;
}

#prev-btn:hover, #next-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#prev-btn {
    left: 20px;
}

#next-btn {
    right: 20px;
}

#nav-btns {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.slide-nav-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 3px;
}
.slide-nav-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
top:0;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
<section class="slider">
    <div id="block-for-slider">
        <div id="viewport">
            <ul id="slidewrapper" class="slider__list">
                <li class="slide slide--blue">
                   <h1 class="slider__headline"></h1>
                    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()" class="slider-btn"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="slide slide--pink ">
                   <h1 class="slider__headline"></h1>
                    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()" class="slider-btn"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="slide slide--grey ">
                   <h1 class="slider__headline"></h1>
                    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()" class="slider-btn"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-btns" class="slider__button-list">
                <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
                <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
                <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Буду очень благодарна за помощь

Comment: Вы не пробовали указать z-index?

Comment: Мало кода Вы сбросили. Не получается увидеть Вашу проблему и поискать решение

Answer (score 0):

в `.header` добавьте `z-index: 9`
в `#slidewrapper` добавьте `z-index: 8`

По идеи, должно помочь. )